# Changing font size of button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay this may be really simple, but every attempt  I make the console throws up various errors. If i have `if(GUI.Button(new Rect(x, y, Screen.width, z), "play")) {` How would I go about changing the size of the text. I have a custom GuiSkin used on the text, but I'm unsure how to change the font size of the text without using the inspector - I am using unity. What I am trying to do is change the font size depending on the screen resolution.

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/changing-text-size-relative-to-screen.102876/ Might help

Comment: Seems pretty in depth, think I may have found the correct part thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have create your GUiSkin object, first you can using inspector to change GuiSkin.Button.FontSize. Then apply this setting in you button.

```
public GUISkin yourGuiSkinObject;
void OnGUI()
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), "Test", yourGuiSkinObject.button))
    {
    //Do something.
    }
}
```

Second you can using script to change fontSize. And change the size depend on the screen's height.

```
public GUISkin yourGuiSkinObject;
void Start()
{
    int scale = Screen.height / 20;
    yourGuiSkinObject.button.fontsize = scale;
}

void OnGui()
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), "Test", yourGuiSkinObject.button))
    {
    }
}
```